# How to force-close (discard) all open documents in Preview and/or TextMate?

Tags: macos, textmate, preview

I have this issue with both Preview and TextMate, and maybe there's a common solution to this, if not, feel free to direct me to fixing one or the other.

I have literally years' worth (hundreds and hundreds) of random screenclips and random scratch text files open in these two apps. Some of these chunks of data are 10s or 100s of MB. They're "untitled" (never saved) documents, and so trying to close them triggers the "save, discard, cancel" dialog. I don't have the patience to sit and Discard all of them manually, and at this point if I haven't seen these things in months or years I probably don't need to review them first. The apps are too smart for their own good-- these open "unsaved" documents are kept around through quits, force quits, etc. The apps are trying to help me. I just want to flush all the documents.

It's gotten so bad that I don't use either app unless I really have to because they are now so bloated and confused and slow. Dumb situation.

Anyone got any good ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Check for a SavedState folder in ~/Library. Force quit the app if you need to, delete the app's savedState folder contents [some apps may be an alias - delete the original's contents, leave the alias in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders to empty out before launching the app.

For Preview:

`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Autosave Information`

For TextMate:

`~/Library/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Session`

(Thanks to @Tetsujin for the pointer in the right direction.)

Answer (score 0):

Force quit Preview, if it's running.

Then delete these two folders:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`

`rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Autosave\ Information`

Next time you open Preview, all the unsaved documents you had open are gone!

Verified with macOS 13.4